# A link always having the dashed style

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a page where there're links with anchors and all the links are anchors leading to the same page but different places on it. A link should always have "dashed" style and never be underlined. This doesn't work as untented:

```
   a:hover, a:link, a:active .link-anchor {
     border-bottom: 1px dashed #aabbccdd ;
     text-decoration: dashed !important;
  }
```

Comment: Please provide more code or a jsFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined invalid color code as shown below:

```
border-bottom: 1px dashed #aabbccdd;
                          // ^^^ there should be 3 or 6 characters
```

It should be:

```
border-bottom: 1px dashed #aabbcc;
```

For more details about css colors, Visit [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_colors.asp).

```css
a.link-anchor:hover, a.link-anchor:link, a.link-anchor:active {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #aabbcc;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor <a href="#" class="link-anchor">Dashed Link</a> sit amet <a href="#">Normal Link</a> Lorem ipsum dolor <a href="#" class="link-anchor">Dashed Link</a> sit amet <a href="#" class="link-anchor">Dashed Link</a> Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
```

Comment: how can I make `a:hover, a:link, a:active ` apply only to the links with the class `.link-anchor` and not affects other links?

Comment: Change your selector to `a.link-anchor:hover, a.link-anchor:link, a.link-anchor:active`. I'll update in my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Muhammad said, I think the rule is also wrong

If you want to add the class you should repeat the `.link-anchor`

```
a.link-anchor:hover, a.link-anchor:link, a.link-anchor:active  {
```

or

```
a:hover, a:link, a:active, .link-anchor {
```

Also, if your class does "border bottom dashed" don't call it "link-anchor" but "dashed-underline" for example